# How to say Adonainu Moreinu VeRabeinu in Aramaic

Tags: rabbis, grammar-dikduk, chasidut-hasidism, aramaic

I have heard people translate "Adoneinu Moreinu VeRabeinu" (*please* don't ask where) into Aramaic as "Adonana Morana Verabana". I assume that the "a" is an aleph at the end. However, I realized that Adonana should translate as Ha'adon (*the* teacher) rather then Adoneinu.

How do you translate "our" in Aramaic?

Comment: of interest: Aramaic Grammar #4 chart at the bottom of this page: http://www.vbm-torah.org/talmud2/vocab.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting confused between Biblical Aramaic and Babylonian Talmudic Aramaic. In Biblical Aramaic, the first person plural possessive suffix is -*na* (נא-). *Adonana* (אדוננא) means "our lord", not *the* lord. "The lord" would be *adona* (אדונא), with the addition of an *aleph* only. As such, the phrase that you are looking for would be *Adonana Marana veRabbana* (אדוננא מרנא ורבנא).

In Babylonian Talmudic Aramaic, the first person plural possessive suffix is -*an* (ן-). The phrase would be rendered as *Adonan Maran veRabban* (אדונן מרן ורבן).

If you want to see this in an Aramaic textbook, you can consult the following:

- Alger F. Johns, *A Short Grammar of Biblical Aramaic* (Michigan: Andrews University Press, 1972), 13; (pdf available [here](http://berryosfiles.com/adoniqam/Aramith/A%20short%20grammar%20on%20Biblical%20Aramaic.pdf))
- [Yitzhak Frank, *Grammar for Gemara and Targum Onkelos* (Jerusalem: Ariel, 2009)](http://books.google.co.cr/books?id=My4YBfzqOHQC&dq=Yitzhak%20Frank,%20Grammar%20for%20Gemara%20and%20Targum%20Onkelos&source=gbs_navlinks_s), §8.3. In the chart, he compares "Talmud Bavli Aramaic" with "Onkelos Aramaic", and you'll note that in this instance Onkelos is the same as Biblical Aramaic.

Comment: aha, so Sifra, Malka (Hamelech) is in Eretz Israel Aramaic.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, No - that's also in Babylonian Aramaic. The definite article is an *aleph* on the ends of words whichever Aramaic you are speaking. I only included that part in my first paragraph because you asked about that in relation to the word *adonana*. Sorry if that was confusing of me.

Comment: Re: your second paragraph. You sure that's not "our master, our teachers, and our rabbis"?

Comment: @SethJ - Yes, I'm positive. Unfortunately, Biblical Aramaic doesn't differentiate between the singular and the plural noun when they feature a first person plural suffix, but BT Aramaic does. If you wanted to pluralise each of those nouns, you would get Adonayin Maranayin veRabbanayin. (As Frank points out, the "common" pronunciation of this would be Adonin Maranin veRabbanin).

Comment: Interesting. Hence my uncertainty in my first paragraph. But then what about the examples of Rabban and Maran? And why isn't it Adonanan?

Comment: Argh. Sorry, @SethJ - that's my stupidity. Let's call it a momentary lapse of reason :) Don't know why but my brain configured *maran* and *rabban* as the words that I was adding the suffix to. Fixing that now!

Comment: Ahh, so we agree.

Answer (score 1):

I believe either "an" or "ein" would most likely be the correct suffix. This would be Adonan/Adonein (not Adonanan/Adoneinan).

Moreinu is be a bit different, since it is a weak consonant at the end. First of all, the "o" gets reduced to a Patah.  I initially thought of Zimmun.  The MeZamen calls "My teachers" first.  I thought it should be similar vocalization at the beginning (Shvah).  But then I realized that's because it's plural, and the Patah is further reduced to a Shvah.  In singular it's Maran; think R' Yosef Karo.

As for Rabbeinu, it would be Rabban. Think Rabban Gamliel, for example.

Comment: Can you write the words you are saying in Hebrew letters too so people are sure to understand what you are saying exactly. Transliteration is never an exact science.

Comment: Not totally sure I can do that with the tools at my disposal.  I just tried a bit, and it didn't go well. Had to abandon my edit.

Comment: About Maran, though, isn't RaMBa"M called Maran by the B"Y or somebody?  And I think the Tur is also called something similar by the Ba"Ch, though I'm not totally sure.

Comment: @DoubleAA, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maran

Comment: @DoubleAA, I'm still not using Ashuri, but is this clearer?

Comment: -1, because Rabban Gamliel's title is not Aramaic.  It is Roshei Teivot for Rebbi Nasi, since he was also the Nasi.

Comment: @DoubleAA, see this headline: http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/article.php?p=160906

Comment: And @AdamMosheh, you come out of hiding to downvote me? How rude. See: http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/12491-rabban

Comment: @SethJ - Nevertheless, the article that you referred me to explicitly says that the title *Rabban* was a title given exlusively to the presidents of the Sanhedrin. Hence, I still reserve my right to downvote.