# Good Talmudic Grammar resource for one unfamiliar with grammar in general?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, grammar-dikduk, aramaic

Inspired by: [How to say Adonainu Moreinu VeRabeinu in Aramaic](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27088/how-to-say-adonainu-moreinu-verabeinu-in-aramaic)

I'd like to understand Talmudic/Aramaic Grammar a little better and am looking for a good resource that will break it down for me.

However, my understanding of grammar in general is very weak, especially the terms  used to describe the various grammatical structures (binyanim). When I see terms like "*reflexive*" or *"po'el yotzei"* to describe the grammatical structure, I have no idea what that means, and I just sort of tune it out.

Is there a good grammatical resource for Talmudic/Aramaic grammar out there that doesn't assume I know anything about grammar in general?

One of the answer to the question linked to above mentioned Yitzhak Frank's  Grammar for Gemara and Targum Onkelos. Would that fit the bill? I [found it on Google Books](http://books.google.co.cr/books?id=My4YBfzqOHQC&dq=Yitzhak%20Frank,%20Grammar%20for%20Gemara%20and%20Targum%20Onkelos&source=gbs_navlinks_s) and glanced through it, but I wasn't sure.

---

I once picked up a copy of [*English Grammar for Students of Spanish* by Emily Spinelli](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0934034222). Instead of assuming you knew the grammatical jargon and jumping right into the spanish, it would first explain the English grammatical rule. ([This review](http://www.amazon.com/review/R3O5OVUAVIKG0W/ref=cm_cr_dp_title?ie=UTF8&ASIN=0934034222&nodeID=283155&store=books) explains it well). It looks like this is part of a [series of books on various languages](http://books.google.co.cr/books/about/English_Grammar_for_Students_of_Spanish.html?id=-hxZLwEACAAJ&redir_esc=y#similarbooks_anchor) (but not Aramaic).

This is pretty much what I'm looking for, but with Aramaic.

---

Here's an example that made me realize I need to brush up on my grammar, trying to figure out what the word "משתבח" means:

[Berachot 6A](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=6&format=pdf) says:

> ומי משתבח קוב"ה בשבחייהו דישראל

[Jastrow translates it](http://www.tyndalearchive.com/tabs/jastrow/ppages/JastrowP388641.gif) (middle of the second column) as:

> Does the L-rd pride himself on the praises of Israel?

But Jastrow [also translates](http://www.tyndalearchive.com/tabs/jastrow/ppages/JastrowP388384.gif) (bottom of second column) "משתבח" as *"to praise one's self"*

Soncino translates it as:

> Does, then, the Holy One, blessed be He, sing the praises of Israel?

But is the Soncino using the version [found in the Ein Yaakov](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47606&pgnum=61)?

> ומי משבח קוב"ה בשבחייהו דישראל

Very confusing.

Comment: [po'el yotzei](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_verb)

Comment: Are you unfamiliar with _grammar_ itself (technical jargon confuses you, various sets of rules confuse you, etc.), or are you unfamiliar (aka _untrained_) with Aramaic Grammar in particular (how grammar rules are used - or altered - in Aramaic, as distinct from English)?

Comment: @SethJ: Unfamiliar with grammar itself. For the most part, I know what sounds/looks right and wrong, but couldn't tell you why or what it was called technically. That's why I'm looking for something that will teach me Aramaic Grammar, but won't assume that I understand the technical jargon.

Comment: I have a book at home for *biblical Hebrew* (not Aramaic) that, for each grammatical concept, explains how it works in English and then how that same idea works in Hebrew.  Hebrew is not the same as Aramaic, but they share a lot.  Would that be helpful to you?

Comment: @monica: it would definitely help

Comment: I don't know if this would be useful, but as far as Biblical Hebrew grammar goes, a great reference book is Ben-Zeev's ["Talmud Lashon Ivri"](http://tinyurl.com/arpu7me). It's a bit old, but in my opinion, still the best I've seen. You're not going to get any understanding of the English terminology, but the Hebrew jargon (like *poel yotzei*) is all there.

Comment: @Menachem, this is the book I was talking about: http://www.amazon.com/Grammatical-Concepts-101-Biblical-Hebrew/dp/0801046947/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1363375352&sr=8-1&keywords=biblical+hebrew+101

Comment: @MonicaCellio: that looks like exactly what I'm looking for in Aramaic, but as you said, it should still help a lot.

Comment: I think you might be making a mistake to look for a book on Aramaic grammar that is going to do everything for you. I think you need a book on Aramaic grammar, and a book on grammar in general (terminology, etc).

Comment: @ShimonbM: See my update. If there is no such thing for Aramaic then I'll need a solution as you described.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/statusinaramic

Comment: There's a series of lectures on the topic from WebYeshiva here: http://www.webyeshiva.org/class.php?cid=888

Comment: @Ephraim: That looks very promising. You should add it as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

There is a *kuntress* (pamphlet / small thin paperback book) called *[Aiding Talmud Study](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0873064283)* put together by Rabbi [Aryeh Carmell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryeh_Carmell). Included within is a concise summary of many points of the Dikduk/Grammar of the Aramaic of the Talmud Babli. I'm not sure whether or not it is still in print, but this is without a doubt an **incredible** resource for Torah learning that anyone serious about knowing probably all of the general rules behind how the Gemara's pronoun declensions and verb conjugations needs to own (or, at the very least, to spend a solid amount of time studying).

Answer (score 1):

I'll recommend **[A Manual of Babylonian Jewish Aramaic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0819113638)** by David Marcus.

From the preface:

> The method adopted is the inductive one whereby grammar is learnt directly as it is encountered in the text... To work with this manual the student is expected to have some knowledge of Hebrew but not of any other Aramaic dialect. The manual is hence geared primarily for beginners in Talmud and Jewish studies, but it is hoped that more advanced students will profit from it as well.

That is the basic information you need to know about it. The manual contains in total several texts from throughout the Talmud, and they are used as examples to teach the grammar contained within.

[Here is a Google preview/examples.](https://books.google.com/books?id=9H0OAAAAYAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=cave)